# How clean notification when close app like spotify?

Tags: android, spotify

I have a service for radio, that show a notification to identify stop and playing, but when I kill the application by swipe, I can't clear the notification

```
PendingIntent openAppIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(RadioService.this, 0, new Intent(RadioService.this, GeneralActivity.class), 0);
            Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(RadioService.this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_pause_lx)
                    .setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.radio) + " " + getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentIntent(openAppIntent)
                    .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause, getString(R.string.stop), PendingIntent.getBroadcast(RadioService.this, 0, new Intent(ACTION_PAUSE), 0))
                    .addAction(0, getString(R.string.open), openAppIntent)
                    .build();

            mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
            registerReceiver(mActionsReceiver, new IntentFilter(ACTION_PAUSE));
```

Answer (score 0):

Call this in you activity's `onDestroy()`:

```
NotificationManager ntfManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
ntfManager.cancelAll();
```